# I'd like to USE the application - I DO NOT want to see it's icon wiggle!

Tags: unity, launcher

Apparently it seems that the designers of Unity operates under the current logic:

If a user types 'gimp' into the launcher this means

**A: If Gimp is not running:**

The user wants to start gimp.

or

**B: If Gimp is already running:**

the user wants to see the gimp-icon in the launcher wiggle for a couple of seconds. The user is not at all interested in switching to the Gimp - nope - that's not why the user typed Gimp. Typing Gimp means: Let me see a wiggling Gimp-icon!

However - I'm an old-fashioned kinda' guy. When I type 'Gimp' into a launcher it means that I would like to actually USE Gimp!

Is there a way to tell unity to bring Gimp (or any other application) to the front with focus as a response to me typing 'Gimp' (or any other application name) in the launcher?

Comment: Did you try alt+tab?

Comment: yep - but that's another topic.

I have loads of memory and often have +10 apps open. Alt-tabbing is doable, but it's much quicker to just type SUPER + application name.

The current behaviour makes no sense at all.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you're more comfortable using a search based graphical launcher but you feel unity is a little slow, I recommend you take a look at [synapse](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synapse/).

It provides pretty much the same functionality as dash, but I find it to be a lot faster. It also provides the functionality you ask for.